# Azure cmdlets - Session is invalid when using two-factor authentication

Tags: powershell, azure

I manage a lot of Azure subscriptions and use the Get-AzureSubscription quite frequently to list subscriptions to which I have access.

Recently I added two-factor authentication to my account. And now I get an odd error for some commands. I can login using the Add-AzureAccount but when I then try toi list subscriptions I get the error "Get-AzureSubscription : `AADSTS16000: Session is invalid due to expiration or recent password change`.

Has anyone else seen this? I'd appreciate any ideas how to circumvent this.

Here's what I do:

```
PS C:\ > add-azureaccount

Id                             Type       Subscriptions                          Tenants
--                             ----       -------------                          -------
username@domain.com            User       xxxxxx-yyyyyy   xxxxxx-yyyyyy
                                          xxxxxx-yyyyyy
                                          xxxxxx-yyyyyy
                                          xxxxxx-yyyyyy
                                          xxxxxx-yyyyyy
                                          xxxxxx-yyyyyy
                                          xxxxxx-yyyyyy


    PS C:\ > Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId 'xxxxxx-yyyyyy'
    PS C:\ > select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId 'xxxxxx-yyyyyy'
    PS C:\ > Get-AzureSubscription -ExtendedDetails
    Get-AzureSubscription : AADSTS16000: Session is invalid due to expiration or recent password change.
    Trace ID: 6fcfa2da-7d7a-43ba-8230-a227312b535b
    Correlation ID: 7206fefd-29fa-4103-ba4f-eb15350a0754
    Timestamp: 2015-04-01 17:57:28Z
    At line:1 char:1
    + Get-AzureSubscription -ExtendedDetails
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureSubscription], AadAuthenticationFailedException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.GetAzureSubscriptionCommand
```

Comment: I get the same error when calling Add-AzureAccount on Windows 10

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this @Yooakim ? hitting the exact same issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm have same problem and to solvent start using Azure PublishFileSettings to manage my 32 subscriptions through certificates.

There is steps to add Azure subscriptions from PowerShell:

1. Open Browser on https://manage.windowsazure.com and add your credentials as Service-Admin or Co-Admin
2. Use PowerShell and download the publish file settings with this cmdlet:

   ```
    Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
   ```
3. At this point a browser redirect to download a file; you need to save it.
4. Them you need to import this file with the certificate using:

   ```
    Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile -PublishSettingsFile "C:\Azure\PublishSettingsFile\MySubscripcion-credentials.publishsettings"
   ```
5. Now you are ready to list the Azure Subscription without a password or expired credential as diferent to use Add-AzureAccount.

   ```
    Get-AzureSubscription| ft SubscriptionName,CurrentStorageAccountName,SubscriptionId -AutoSize
   ```
6. Finally now you can select subscription want to manage.

   ```
    Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "MySubscripcion"
   ```

I'm hope this procedure help you.

Regards